# Create a web worker when a function is called | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, optimization, artificial-intelligence, web-worker

I have a Tic Tac Toe 3D game which I want to optimize because at this moment, it crashes my web browser. It uses the MiniMax alpha-beta-pruning algorithm and I've split the code in 3 different files:

TTT3D 
|-js 
  |---init.js # where I define all variables (as winningCombos, human, computer etc)

  |---worker.js # the miniMax algorithm and at the end, I send as message the `choice` variable

  |---ticAlpha.js # the worker is built and trying to get the response
|-index.html

Here is the code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe 3D</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="intro">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" style="text-align: center;">
                    <h1>Hi there! Let's play <b>Tic Tac Toe</b>! Choose your player!</h1>
                    <button value="X" id="X" onclick="startGame('X')">X</button>
                    <button value="O" id="O" onclick="startGame('O')">O</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="board" class="hidden">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row bottom">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2 boxContent">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <h2>X</h2>
                        </li>
                        <li style="float: right !important;">
                            <input type="text" name="xPlayerScore" id="xPlayerScore" value="-" readonly>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 boxContent">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <h2>O</h2>
                        </li>
                        <li style="float: right !important;">
                            <input type="text" name="oPlayerScore" id="oPlayerScore" value="-" readonly>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <button class="col-md-2" onclick="playAgain()" style="margin-left: 7px;">
                    <img src="images/again.png" width="16">
                Play Again
                </button>


                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="canvas1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="tile" boardcol="0" boardrow="0" boardlevel="0" onclick="makeMove(0)" id="0"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="1" boardrow="0" boardlevel="0" onclick="makeMove(1)" id="1"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="2" boardrow="0" boardlevel="0"onclick="makeMove(2)" id="2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="tile" boardcol="0" boardrow="1" boardlevel="0"onclick="makeMove(3)" id="3"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="1" boardrow="1" boardlevel="0"onclick="makeMove(4)" id="4"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="2" boardrow="1" boardlevel="0"onclick="makeMove(5)" id="5"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="tile" boardcol="0" boardrow="2" boardlevel="0"onclick="makeMove(6)" id="6"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="1" boardrow="2" boardlevel="0"onclick="makeMove(7)" id="7"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="2" boardrow="2" boardlevel="0"onclick="makeMove(8)" id="8"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="canvas2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="tile" boardcol="0" boardrow="0" boardlevel="1"onclick="makeMove(9)" id="9"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="1" boardrow="0" boardlevel="1"onclick="makeMove(10)" id="10"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="2" boardrow="0" boardlevel="1"onclick="makeMove(11)" id="11"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="tile" boardcol="0" boardrow="1" boardlevel="1"onclick="makeMove(12)" id="12"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="1" boardrow="1" boardlevel="1"onclick="makeMove(13)" id="13"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="2" boardrow="1" boardlevel="1"onclick="makeMove(14)" id="14"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="tile" boardcol="0" boardrow="2" boardlevel="1"onclick="makeMove(15)" id="15"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="1" boardrow="2" boardlevel="1"onclick="makeMove(16)" id="16"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="2" boardrow="2" boardlevel="1"onclick="makeMove(17)" id="17"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="canvas3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="tile" boardcol="0" boardrow="0" boardlevel="2"onclick="makeMove(18)" id="18"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="1" boardrow="0" boardlevel="2"onclick="makeMove(19)" id="19"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="2" boardrow="0" boardlevel="2"onclick="makeMove(20)" id="20"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="tile" boardcol="0" boardrow="1" boardlevel="2"onclick="makeMove(21)" id="21"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="1" boardrow="1" boardlevel="2"onclick="makeMove(22)" id="22"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="2" boardrow="1" boardlevel="2"onclick="makeMove(23)" id="23"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="tile" boardcol="0" boardrow="2" boardlevel="2"onclick="makeMove(24)" id="24"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="1" boardrow="2" boardlevel="2"onclick="makeMove(25)" id="25"></div>
                <div class="tile" boardcol="2" boardrow="2" boardlevel="2"onclick="makeMove(26)" id="26"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ticAlpha.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

init.js

```
var winningCombos   = new Array();

winningCombos[0]    = [0, 1, 2];
winningCombos[1]    = [3, 4, 5];
winningCombos[2]    = [6, 7, 8];

// Per columns

winningCombos[3]    = [0, 3, 6];
winningCombos[4]    = [1, 4, 7];
winningCombos[5]    = [2, 5, 8];

// Diagonals

winningCombos[6]    = [0, 4, 8];
winningCombos[7]    = [2, 4, 6];


// Second board

//Per lines

winningCombos[8]    = [9, 10, 11];
winningCombos[9]    = [12, 13, 14];
winningCombos[10]   = [15, 16, 17];

// Per columns

winningCombos[11]   = [9, 12, 15];
winningCombos[12]   = [10, 13, 16];
winningCombos[13]   = [11, 14, 17];

// Diagonals

winningCombos[14]   = [9, 13, 17];
winningCombos[15]   = [11, 13, 15];


// Third board

// Per lines

winningCombos[16]   = [18, 19, 20];
winningCombos[17]   = [21, 22, 23];
winningCombos[18]   = [24, 25, 26];

// Per columns

winningCombos[19]   = [18, 21, 24];
winningCombos[20]   = [19, 22, 25];
winningCombos[21]   = [20, 23, 26];

// Diagonals

winningCombos[22]   = [18, 22, 26];
winningCombos[23]   = [20, 22, 24];


// 3D Winning

winningCombos[24]   = [0, 13, 26];
winningCombos[25]   = [20, 13, 6];

// Per lines

winningCombos[26]   = [0, 10, 20];
winningCombos[27]   = [3, 13, 23];
winningCombos[28]   = [6, 16, 26];

var free            = ' ';
var boardSize       = 27;
var board           = new Array();
var activePlayer    = 'Human';
var i;
var choice;
var human;
var humanTurn;
var computer;
var computerTurn;
var humanWin = 0;
var computerWin = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#intro").addClass("hidden");
        $("#board").removeClass("hidden");
    });
});

function startGame(player) {
    for (i = 0; i < boardSize; i += 1) {
        board[i] = free;
    }

    activePlayer = 'Human';

    if (player == "X") {
        human = "X";
        humanTurn = "<p>X</p>";
        computer = "O";
        computerTurn = "<p>O</p>";
    } else {
        human = "O";
        humanTurn = "<p>O</p>";
        computer = "X";
        computerTurn = "<p>X</p>";
    }
}
```

ticAlpha.js

```
function makeMove(pos) {
    if (board[pos] === free && !gameOver(board)) {
        board[pos] = human;
        document.getElementById(pos).innerHTML = humanTurn;

        if (!gameOver(board)) {
            activePlayer = 'Computer';
            makeComputerMove();
        }
    }
}

function makeComputerMove() {
    // miniMax(board, 0, -Infinity, +Infinity);

    var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
    worker.postMessage('its time');

    worker.onmessage = function(event) {
        var move = event.data;
    };

    board[move] = computer;
    document.getElementById(move).innerHTML = computerTurn;
    choice = [];
    activePlayer = 'Human';
}

function score(possibleGame) {
    var score = getWinner(possibleGame);

    if (score === 3) {
        return 0;
    } else if (score === 1) {
        return -1;
    } else if (score === 2) {
        return 1;
    }
}

function miniMax(node, depth, alpha, beta) {
    if (getWinner(node) !== 0) {
        return score(node);
    }

    depth += 1;
    // var scores   = new Array();
    // var moves    = new Array();
    var availableMoves = getAvailableMoves(node);
    var move, result, possibleGame;
    if (activePlayer === 'Computer'){
        for (var i = 0; i < availableMoves.length; i += 1) {
            move = availableMoves[i];
            possibleGame = generateNewGame(move, node);
            result = miniMax(possibleGame, depth, alpha, beta);
            node = undoMove(node, move);

            if (result > alpha) {
                alpha = result;
                if (depth === 1) {
                    choice = move;
                } else if (alpha >= beta) {
                    return alpha;
                }
            }
        }
        return alpha;
    } else if (activePlayer === 'Human') { 
        for (var i = 0; i < availableMoves.length; i += 1) {
            move = availableMoves[i];
            possibleGame = generateNewGame(move, node);
            result = miniMax(possibleGame, depth, alpha, beta);
            node = undoMove(node, move);

            if (result < beta) {
                beta = result;
                if (depth === 1) {
                    choice = move;
                } else if (alpha >= beta) {
                    return beta;
                }
            }
        }

        return beta;
    }
}

function undoMove(possibleGame, move) {
    possibleGame[move] = free;
    changePlayerTurn();
    return possibleGame;
}

function getAvailableMoves(tempBoard) {
    var availableMoves = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < boardSize; i += 1) {
        if (board[i] === free) {
            availableMoves.push(i);
        }
    }
    return availableMoves;
}

function generateNewGame(move, possibleGame) {
    var piece = changePlayerTurn();
    possibleGame[move] = piece;
    return possibleGame;
}

function changePlayerTurn() {
    var turn;
    if (activePlayer === 'Computer') {
        turn = computer;
        activePlayer = 'Human';
    } else {
        turn = human;
        activePlayer = 'Computer';
    }

    return turn;
}

function gameOver(tempBoard) {
    if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 1) {
        alert("You won!");
        humanWin += 1;
        if (human === "X") {
            document.getElementById("xPlayerScore").value = humanWin;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("oPlayerScore").value = humanWin;
        }
    } else if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 2) {
        alert("Computer won!");
        computerWin += 1;
        if (computer === "X") {
            document.getElementById("xPlayerScore").value = computerWin;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("oPlayerScore").value = computerWin;
        }
    } else if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 3) {
        alert("The game was a draw!");
    }
    return 1;
}

function getWinner(tempBoard) {
    for (i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i += 1) {
        if (tempBoard[winningCombos[i][0]] === human &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][1]] === human &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][2]] === human) {
            return 1; // human won
        } else if (tempBoard[winningCombos[i][0]] === computer &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][1]] === computer &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][2]] === computer) {
            return 2; // computer won
        }
    }

    if (tempBoard.indexOf(free) >= 0) {
        return 0; // not finished yet
    }

    return 3; // the game was a draw
}

function gameOver(tempBoard) {
    if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 1) {
        alert("You won!");
        humanWin += 1;
        if (human === "X") {
            document.getElementById("xPlayerScore").value = humanWin;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("oPlayerScore").value = humanWin;
        }
    } else if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 2) {
        alert("Computer won!");
        computerWin += 1;
        if (computer === "X") {
            document.getElementById("xPlayerScore").value = computerWin;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("oPlayerScore").value = computerWin;
        }
    } else if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 3) {
        alert("The game was a draw!");
    }
    return 1;
}

function getWinner(tempBoard) {
    for (i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i += 1) {
        if (tempBoard[winningCombos[i][0]] === human &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][1]] === human &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][2]] === human) {
            return 1; // human won
        } else if (tempBoard[winningCombos[i][0]] === computer &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][1]] === computer &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][2]] === computer) {
            return 2; // computer won
        }
    }

    if (tempBoard.indexOf(free) >= 0) {
        return 0; // not finished yet
    }

    return 3; // the game was a draw
}

function playAgain() {
    if (getWinner(board) != 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < boardSize; j += 1) {
            document.getElementById(j).innerHTML = "";
        }
        resetBoard();
    }
}

function resetBoard() {
    for (i = 0; i < boardSize; i += 1) {
        board[i] = free;
    }
}
```

worker.js

```
function miniMax(node, depth, alpha, beta) {
    if (getWinner(node) !== 0) {
        return score(node);
    }

    depth += 1;
    // var scores   = new Array();
    // var moves    = new Array();
    var availableMoves = getAvailableMoves(node);
    var move, result, possibleGame;
    if (activePlayer === 'Computer'){
        for (var i = 0; i < availableMoves.length; i += 1) {
            move = availableMoves[i];
            possibleGame = generateNewGame(move, node);
            result = miniMax(possibleGame, depth, alpha, beta);
            node = undoMove(node, move);

            if (result > alpha) {
                alpha = result;
                if (depth === 1) {
                    choice = move;
                } else if (alpha >= beta) {
                    return alpha;
                }
            }
        }
        return alpha;
    } else if (activePlayer === 'Human') { 
        for (var i = 0; i < availableMoves.length; i += 1) {
            move = availableMoves[i];
            possibleGame = generateNewGame(move, node);
            result = miniMax(possibleGame, depth, alpha, beta);
            node = undoMove(node, move);

            if (result < beta) {
                beta = result;
                if (depth === 1) {
                    choice = move;
                } else if (alpha >= beta) {
                    return beta;
                }
            }
        }

        return beta;
    }
}

function undoMove(possibleGame, move) {
    possibleGame[move] = free;
    changePlayerTurn();
    return possibleGame;
}

function getAvailableMoves(tempBoard) {
    var availableMoves = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < boardSize; i += 1) {
        if (board[i] === free) {
            availableMoves.push(i);
        }
    }
    return availableMoves;
}

function generateNewGame(move, possibleGame) {
    var piece = changePlayerTurn();
    possibleGame[move] = piece;
    return possibleGame;
}

function changePlayerTurn() {
    var turn;
    if (activePlayer === 'Computer') {
        turn = computer;
        activePlayer = 'Human';
    } else {
        turn = human;
        activePlayer = 'Computer';
    }

    return turn;
}

function gameOver(tempBoard) {
    if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 1) {
        alert("You won!");
        humanWin += 1;
        if (human === "X") {
            document.getElementById("xPlayerScore").value = humanWin;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("oPlayerScore").value = humanWin;
        }
    } else if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 2) {
        alert("Computer won!");
        computerWin += 1;
        if (computer === "X") {
            document.getElementById("xPlayerScore").value = computerWin;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("oPlayerScore").value = computerWin;
        }
    } else if (getWinner(tempBoard) === 3) {
        alert("The game was a draw!");
    }
    return 1;
}

function getWinner(tempBoard) {
    for (i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i += 1) {
        if (tempBoard[winningCombos[i][0]] === human &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][1]] === human &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][2]] === human) {
            return 1; // human won
        } else if (tempBoard[winningCombos[i][0]] === computer &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][1]] === computer &&
            tempBoard[winningCombos[i][2]] === computer) {
            return 2; // computer won
        }
    }

    if (tempBoard.indexOf(free) >= 0) {
        return 0; // not finished yet
    }

    return 3; // the game was a draw
}

onmessage = function(e) {
    miniMax(board, 0, -Infinity, Infinity);
    postMessage(choice);
};
```

The problem is that the variable `move` is always undefined and even if I do a `console.log()` inside the `worker.onmessage` function, it doesn't display anything.

It's more likely to misunderstood the concept of what a web worker is and should be used but I am trying for more than 24 hours to solve it and it feels like 0 progress. Would appreciate your help if possible. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't make your worker every time a function is called.  Make the worker up front and communicate with it over the course of your apps lifetime.  Also, what is your exact problem?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: The problem is that the variable `move` is always undefined. (ReferenceError: move is not defined). Even when I do a console.log() inside the `worker.onmessage` function, it doesn't display anything.

Comment: What about `index.html`

Comment: Just added `index.html` too.

Answer (score 0):

Well one issue is that it looks like you are expecting the worker to have access to all of the variables that are available on the main thread, it won't.  You have to maintain board state in both the main thread and worker and synchronize them through messages.  That's another reason to make the worker up front and keep the same one throughout the lifetime of the app.

Consider your call to `miniMax(board, 0, -Infinity, Infinity);` in `worker.js`.  This call is likely throwing an error in the thread because `board` isn't defined so `miniMax` tries to access it in the function body and throws.

Additionally, you also call `postMessage(choice)` in your worker, but `choice` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: I've made the `worker` in the `init.js` file and I've also sent the `board` from `ticAlpha.js` to `worker.js` with `postMessage`. In the `worker.js` I define a new variable `var board = e.data;`. And the `choice` is defined now. It still doesn't want to work. Thanks for the help!